# Split CSV and concat suffix from multiple properties into a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have three string properties that are formatted as CSV:

```
string Tap70V = "1,2,3,4" //example data
string Tap100V = "10,20,30,40" //example data
string Tap25V = ".2,.4,.6,.8" //example data
```

I want the following result in a List so I can bind it to a Combobox:

```
".2 Watt 25V"
".4 Watt 25V"
".6 Watt 25V"
".8 Watt 25V"
"1 Watt 70V"
"2 Watt 70V"
"3 Watt 70V"
```

and so on until it shows

`"4 Watt 100V"`

I know I need to union the three properties together, split them by "," into a list then concatenate the suffix "Watt XXV". (not necessarily in that order)

I just can't figure out a good one or two line way to do this

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'll get you started: `Tap70V.Split(',').Select(x => $"{x} Watt 70V")`.

Comment: Don't use string variables/fields/properties and try to "process" their names as if they are data. Variables names are just that: names of variables. Like names of methods are just names of methods. They are not to be understood as some data to be processed by the program; trying to follow such an approach would be conceptually questionable. Instead, perhaps try using something  like a `Dictionary<int, List<float>>` for keeping your data, where the (integer) keys are the voltages, and the values associated with the keys are list of floats which each float being a wattage...

Comment: I do not like what you are trying to do.  But here is answer : string[] results = string.Join(",",new string[] {Tap70V, Tap100V, Tap25V}).Split(new char[] {','}).ToArray();

Comment: Creating the combobox list isn't really that hard. The real question I have: what do you want to map these values to when an option is chosen. How will the program know what to do with those values later?

Comment: That is how the data is stored in the database. Those are the properties from the data model. If they were all in-memory properties or just existing in my program I wouldn't have them like this. So you an mention a better a way to store them but I don't have control over that. Otherwise I wouldn't need to do this in the first place haha.

Comment: I'm using a Converter to create the list on the Combobox binding. another data table stores the value as the human readable "1 Watt 25V". but none of that is important to my question.

Comment: @Vikhram, yes, that was a mistake that I'll fix. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the cleanest way I could figure out to accomplish my question:

```
if (value is IItemLibrarySpeaker s)
        {
            List<string> taps = s.Speaker25VTaps.Split(',').Select(x => $"{x} Watt/25V").ToList();
            taps.AddRange(s.Speaker70VTaps.Split(',').Select(x => $"{x} Watt/70V"));
            taps.AddRange(s.Speaker100VTaps.Split(',').Select(x => $"{x} Watt/100V"));

            return taps;
        }
```

Thanks for the suggestions (even the ones that had nothing to do with my question)

Answer (score 1):

First, you should move the values of your variables into a dictionary structure like below

```
var tbl = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "70V", "1,2,3,4" },
    { "100V", "10,20,30,40" },
    { "25V", ".2,.4,.6,.8" },
};
```

Then you can easily query it out using the below code

```
tbl.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Split(',').Select(y => $"{y} Watt {x.Key}"));
```

The `SelectMany` call flattens the multi-level hierarchy, and returns an `IEnumerable<string>` with the required string. The `$"{y}"` syntax if for an interpolated string, if you don't use a supported version of C#, then you can use a `string.Format` instead of string interpolation

**UPDATE**

Based on the OP's comment, I am providing a way to form the dictionary above

```
var tbl = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { nameof(Tap70V), Tap70V },
    { nameof(Tap100V), Tap100V },
    { nameof(Tap25V), Tap25V },
};
```

By relying on variable names for values is a dangerous practice. If the OP provides, how the value of `70V`, `100V` and `25V` are available, then I can update the answer with a suitable way to adapt that to this solution

Comment: I would still have to parse out those properties the same way to make that dictionary in the first place. If I wasn't using a datamodel from the database then this would be the logical approach to take.

Comment: @beatnikthedan, I presumed a dictionary, since in your current model, I don't see any variable holding the values like `70V, 100V, 25V`. If you have this information available in some variables, then I can tell you how to get the same result, in that situation

Comment: I wouldn't need the key for anything, just the list of values. So there really isn't a point in putting it in a dictionary in the first place. After I convert those values to a list for the UI I don't really need to reference it again. The Xaml Converters take care of all that for me.

Comment: @beatnikthedan A sample message you are expecting is `3 Watt 70V`, notice the `70V` part where you are using the Key

Comment: I'm not saying this won't work or isn't a good idea to structure my specific question this way, it just won't work for my application. There is no need to convert it to a dictionary. Especially since Binding a dictionary to a Xaml control is very problematic. I would need an IEnumerable which I could just create in the query I'd have to create to even get my three properties into a dictionary in the first place. No need to do this middle step.

Answer (score 0):

As per provided sample data i made sample code as below:

```
string Tap70V = "1,2,3,4"; //example data
            string Tap100V = "10,20,30,40"; //example data
            string Tap25V = ".2,.4,.6,.8"; //example data

            var test = new List<string>();
                test.AddRange(Tap70V.Split(',').Select(val => val + " Watt 70V"));
                test.AddRange(Tap100V.Split(',').Select(val => val + " Watt 100V"));
                test.AddRange(Tap25V.Split(',').Select(val => val + " Watt 25V"));
```

In above piece of code, add string objects value into `List<string>` variable named `test`.
For every object data need to split and AddRange into List.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: how do you know that the range of values have something to do with 70V and the range of values have something to do with 25V?

But let's assume you have a sequence of Voltage Text combinations:

```
Voltage | Text
   70   | "1,2,3,4"
  100   | "10,20,30,40"
   25   | ".2,.4,.6,.8"
```

For instance, to create them from your three variables:

```
IEnumerable<VoltageTextCombination> voltageTextCombinations = new VoltageTextCombination[]
{
    new VoltageTextCombination {Voltage =  70, Text = Tap70V},
    new VoltageTextCombination {Voltage = 100, Text = Tap100V},
    new VoltageTextCombination {Voltage =  25, Text = Tap25V},
}
```

I defined a class VoltageTextCombination for this. Of course you could also use an anonymous type for this.

To get your sequence of combo box items, you need to split the Text into a sequence of Watts, and use the correct [SelectMany overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___System_Func___0___1___2__) to get a sequence of Voltage - Watt combinations. After that you use String.Format to convert every Voltage - Watt combination into the text that you want to display:

Constants used in the LINQ below, used to split your input text into Watts, and to format the Voltage - Watt combinations into a string:

```
static readonly char[] separatorChars = new char[] {','};
const string strFormat ="{0} Watt {1}V";
```

The LINQ query:

```
var result = voltageTextCombinations.SelectMany(

    // parameter collectionSelector:
    // input a source element (= one voltageTextCombination)
    // output a sequence (= the text of the combination split into Watts
    combination => combination.Text.Split(separatorChars),

    // parameter resultSelector: take one source element, and one of every watt
    // to make a Voltage - Watt combination
    (voltageTextCombi, splitString) => new
    {
        Voltage = voltageTextCombi.Voltage,
        Watt = splitString,
    })

    // convert every Voltage-Watt combination to one string:
    .Select(voltageWattCombi => String.Format(strFormat,
            voltageWattCombi.Watt,
            voltageWattCombi.Voltage));
```

Simple comme bonjour!

Comment: I don't need to know if it's from 25,70 or 100 properties. I need to know what value I'm converting it to in the question.